# Vim: Have the cursor at the end of buffer at startup

Tags: vim

I need the vim command line options to move the cursor to the end of the buffer when vim starts.
I know about the commands G and $, but thats not what I am asking for. I want these commands to be automatically issued at startup, so the cursor ends up at the last position.

Moving to last line already works:

```
vim [filename] +
```

But that puts the cursor at the beginning of the last line. I want it to be at the last position.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simplest approach:

```
 vim [filename] +"normal G$"
```

If you want it automatically executed without the commandline switches you can look at

```
 :autocmd BufRead *.ext norm! G$
```

Comment: `normal!` in autocommand (does not depend on user mappings), `norm` in +{cmd} (lesser to type).

Comment: Thanks ZyX, you are invited to share all of these tidbits. Where did you get those :)

Comment: `:h normal` shows up `:norm[al][!] {commands} *:norm* *:normal*` and `If the [!] is given, mappings will not be used.`. I always use `:help` to search for lesser typing. But I agree that @Zyx may already have all those tidbits inside his head! :)